# Unable to call function in form application of VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sockets

I am very new new to visual studio. I am using VS2010 and i am trying to create a form application which will have three buttons:
**CONNECT** - a button which provides socket connection to the dsp connected and reads the commands I send( for example a handshake command) and then displays it on the console
**MEASURE** - a button which calculates the parameters I want and
**STOP** - which exits the program and two labels to display my parameters.
The problem is, the code within the CONNECT button has multiple calls for the reading and writing of commands along with socket connection code. What I have observed is that apart from socket connection code, it doesnt call **readData()** or **writeData()** functions. I googled for hours but apparently no success. Please let me know if there is any mistake or if there are any other alternate solutions present to get it working. Thanks in advance.
My code:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>

    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>

    using namespace std;
    #pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

    int m_port = 2500;
    int m_sockId;
    const char START_FIXED = 0x10;
    const char END = 0x16;
    const char START_VAR = 0x68;
    char m_buffer[32768];
    namespace radar {

        using namespace System;
        using namespace System::ComponentModel;
        using namespace System::Collections;
        using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
        using namespace System::Data;
        using namespace System::Drawing;

        public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
        {
        public:
            Form1(void)
            {
                InitializeComponent();

            }

        protected:
            ~Form1()
            {
                if (components)
                {
                    delete components;
                }
            }
        private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  START;
        protected: 

        protected: 
        private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
        private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
        private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
        private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;


        private:
            System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

    #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
            /// <summary>

            void InitializeComponent(void)
            {
                //components initialization
            }

    int setup()
    {
        //Socket connecting code
    }

    bool writeData(const char command, const char length)
    {
        //data write
    }

    int readData()
    {
        //reads the data
    }

    int printData(int length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<=length; i++)
        {
            printf("%i\n", m_buffer[i]);
        }
    return 0;
    }

    #pragma endregion

        private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    const char command[10] = {250, 249, 247, 245, 241, 242, 243, 206, 103, 111};
    unsigned short length;

    //connect
    setup();
    length = readData(); // doesn't call the readData() function defined outside
    if (length >= 0)
        printData(length); //Prints some random set of data from the memory but not the response of the module

    //send and receive 250
    writeData(250, length);
    length = readData();
    if (length>=0)
        printData(length); 

    //send and receive 249
    writeData(command[1],length); // doesn't call the writeData() function
    length = readData();
    if (length >= 0)
        printData(length);
        if (length != 92){

     }


    private: System::Void button2_Click_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) { exit (0);
             }

    private: System::Void button1_Click_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                //measure...
                }
             }
    };
    }
```

PS: It gives me error when I define those functions within this '*private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {* '

Comment: Reduce the size of your sample at least 10 times.

Comment: Hi, sorry if this question is silly, but could you please tell me what do you mean by the sample?

Comment: You posted 400 lines of code and want that somebody will look at it for free? Reduce it to 40 lines first.

Comment: Fair enough, I've tried reducing the unwanted part of the code